# Time machine: exclude items causes long "calculating full size of backup..." delay

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup

The preferences of Time Machine crash when I click options. This is what I did:

I have a new hard disk to back up. I connected the hard disk to my iMac (Mac OS 10.9.2) I accept the invitation to dedicate the disc to Time Machine. I open the preferences, click Option and I try to exclude some items from back ups. I select some files and I click Save. The circle with colors moving appears meaning that is thinking, but it never ends.

I force Quit Applications and select Preferences. I put Time Machine off. I re start the computer. I open again the Preferences > Time Machine. But when I click to option it gets stuck again. I see the files that I excluded from back up and the sentence "calculating size of full backup..." But the circle with colors never ends.

What can I do?

Comment: by "never ends" how long do you mean? Have you let it run overnight?

Comment: @dwightk: no, I have not let it run overnight, I let it run something more than 1 hour (we are talking about the options panel). The problem comes when I select the Applications folder to exclude. Notice that if I do not force quit from preferences I cannot work with the computer, the keyboard does not work.

Comment: I had the same problem under macOS 10.13. The whole thing seems buggy. Try the Apple Bug Reporter and paste back any response here.